# Date Dropdown Filter for PRIME NG table

Tags: angular, filter, primeng-datatable

In Prime NG table we are receiving data from API Response. For DATE column data is received in milliseconds which is getting transformed to date format by following code:

```
{{rowData.errorOccuredTime | date : 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
In Date column we need a Filter for which I have written as following <input *ngSwitchCase="'errorOccuredTime'" type="date" (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, 'equals')">
```

So either way it can work.
Either user can select from calendar or from Dropdown

I have tried dropdown

```
<p- dropdown *ngSwitchCase="'errorOccuredTime'" [options]="col.field" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value, 'grdFilter', 'in')"> 

export class GrdFilterPipe implements PipeTransform { transform(item: any[], key: string, value: number): any { return item.filter(i => i[key] === new Date(value).getTime().toString()); } }
```

No Approach seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use the "value" property for the "let-item" object

   ```
   {{item.value.fromDate}}
   ```
2. And now for the surprise part, you have to provide the "optionLabel" property otherwise you get an empty item in the dropdown.

```html
<p-dropdown
    id="season"
    placeholder="Select a season"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedSeason"
    [options]="seasons"
    optionLabel="fromDate">

    <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
        {{item.value.fromDate | date: 'yyyy'}} - {{item.value.toDate | date: 'yyyy'}}
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template let-item pTemplate="selectedItem">
        {{item.value.fromDate | date: 'yyyy'}} - {{item.value.toDate | date: 'yyyy'}}
    </ng-template>

</p-dropdown>
```